# How does it work if we have different "time-steps" and "LSTM-units"?

Tags: lstm

As I know we can create a `LSTM` layer like:
`model.add(LSTM(units), input_shape = (time-steps, feature_number))`
And the `units` number and `time-steps` number can be different numbers! So how does it work? For ex, if I specify my `LSTM` like this:
`model.add(LSTM(10), input_shape = (1, feature_number))`

How will it feed the network? Shouldn't each `unit` of `LSTM` be 1 `time-step`? So how is it possible when I have 10 `units` but 1 `time-step`?

[image]

Comment: units refers do one recurrent neuron or node. If you have 10 timesteps, each of the neurons would run the 10 timesteps.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal: Please look at the picture that I have added. It seems each time-step relates to only 1 unit!